# JavaScript Building Multiple Temporary Variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I know that there is a .sort() method that can be used to sort arrays in JavaScript but I am trying to build the method myself just for practice. I am trying to just do it for an array of numbers. At the moment, I have it working for 5 numbers in an array but I would like to get it to be dynamic so that it could make an array of anysize. Is there a way to replicate this code easily so that it scales or do I need to go about a whole different approach?

```
var myArray = [3,2,4,5,1];

function sort(array) {
  var max = 0;
  var mid3 = 0;
  var mid2 = 0;
  var mid1 = 0;
  var min = 0;
  var sortArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > max) {
      min = mid1
      mid1 = mid2
      mid2 = mid3
      mid3 = max
      max = array[i];
    } else if (array[i] > mid3) {
      min = mid1
      mid1 = mid2
      mid2 = mid3
      mid3 = array[i];
    } else if (array[i] > mid2) { 
      min = mid1
      mid1 = mid2
      mid2 = array[i];
    } else if (array[i] > mid1) {
      min = mid1
      mid1 = array[i];
    } else {
      min = array[i]
    }
  }
  sortArr.push(max, mid3, mid2, mid1, min);
  return sortArr
}

console.log(sort(myArray))
```

I was thinking of building some sort of variable constructor that would be something like the below and then passing that in to the function so that some of the logic is abstracted but not sure if that is possible. Then you would need some way to build the if else statements and the push method to be updated. I am not sure if there is some simple solution out there that I am missing so any help is appreciated.

```
function varConstruct (num) {
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    "mid" + i;
    }
  }
```

Comment: myArray["mid" + i] ???

Comment: You're making way too many comparisons. Look into quick sort or merge sort - see http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: Probably want to look at recursion if you want to do this cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps utilize the arguments.length method available in javascript. This way you can pass a dynamic number of arguments to your function and still be able to access them all.  Here is a better description of what it does.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length

Hope that helps.